# Show that $(D_t t)$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $B$ be a Banach space, $\epsilon > 0$, and 
$$C_1^0 ([-\epsilon,\epsilon],B) = \{u \in C^0([-\epsilon,\epsilon],B) : tu \in C^1([-\epsilon,\epsilon],B)\}.$$

Denote $\partial/\partial t$ by $D_t$. Show that $(D_t t)$ is an isomorphism from $C_1^0 ([-\epsilon,\epsilon],B)$ onto $C^0([-\epsilon,\epsilon],B)$.

**Note:** I think I've already covered showing that $(D_t t)$ is a bijection. So my main problem is to show that $(D_t t)$ is a continuous operator.

Comment: What is $D_t t$?

Comment: @copper.hat I've edited it: $D_t t$ is the operator that differentiates the product $tu$.

Comment: why not call it $D_t$?

Comment: The question is, what topology is $C^0_1([-\epsilon,\epsilon],B)$ endowed with? If the subspace topology of $C^0$, then $D_tt$ can only be an isomorphism if $B = \{0\}$, for otherwise it's not a closed subspace.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the comment. The topology/norm of $C^1_0$ is really something I've been wondering about as well. I thought that you guys here might have some ideas what that topology "usually" is. Anyway, can I ask you to explain "If the subspace topology of $C^0$, then $D_t t$ can only be an isomorphism if $B=\{ 0 \}$, for otherwise it's not a closed subspace." more?

Comment: If $B \neq \{0\}$, consider any one-dimensional subspace to reduce it to $B = \mathbb{R}$. The function $f(x) = \lvert x - \epsilon/2\rvert$ is the uniform limit of differentiable functions $f_n$, and of course $f_n \in C_1^0$, but $f \notin C^0_1$, since the point of non-differentiability is not smoothed out by multiplying with $t$. So $f \in \overline{C^0_1}\setminus C^0_1$ in the subspace topology.